# Changing length of axis line without lowering its range in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a violin plot in ggplot2. I've set the y limits and added significance brackets wit ggsignif however I am only able to do this if they are expanded above the distribution of data points. If I lower the range two of the significance brackets are removed. Is there a way to expand the plot without increasing the line on the y axis so my significance brackets are still visible?

[image]

Basically, I want to remove the y axis line above 1000 without getting rid of the labels above it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your own data, so I will use the built-in iris dataset here.

There are a couple of ways to achieve the effdct you are looking for: either fake the axis to make it look likes it stops at 1,000, or draw the brackets outside of the panel.

You can do the first method by setting axis breaks from 0 to 1000, removing the y axis line and drawing on an annotation that goes from 0 to 1000 at x = 0.5:

```r
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width * 220, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_violin(fill = NA, size = 1) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "virginica"),
                                 c("setosa", "versicolor"),
                                 c("versicolor", "virginica")), 
              color = "black", y_position = c(1200, 1100, 1000)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1300), breaks = 0:5 * 200, 
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  annotate("segment", x = 0.5, xend = 0.5, y = 0, yend = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("violet", "gray", "orange"), guide = "none") +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

For the second option, set the y limits inside `coord_cartesian` and turn clipping off:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width * 220, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_violin(fill = NA, size = 1) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("setosa", "virginica"),
                                 c("setosa", "versicolor"),
                                 c("versicolor", "virginica")), 
              color = "black", y_position = c(1200, 1100, 1000)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("violet", "gray", "orange"), guide = "none") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(100, 20, 20, 20)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Is there any way to increase the line width of the segment annotation using the first method?

Comment: Yes, use `size = 1` inside annotate (or whatever value you like)